# CentOS, Virtual Box, and Ping

Tags: networking, virtualbox, centos

Ok, long story...

I have two VM's running in Virtual Box. Both are configured with an internal network adapter and a NAT'ed connection (for internet connection only). One VM is running CentOS 5 and the other is Win2k8R2. I setup the internal network with hard coded IP's in the Class C 192.168.xx.xx subnet. I am also running DNS from my host OS. Both VM's can resolve each other's IP's and the Windows box can ping the CentOS box. However, the CentOS box cannot ping the Windows VM. I disabled the Windows firewall so I am pretty sure the its not getting blocked.

At one point I was using VB's DHCP server for the internal network and the CentOS box would get an IP, so eth0 is able to talk, and ping to other external systems work fine.

For the internal network both machines are not using a default gateway since they are both on the same subnet.

Anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: Can you ping the Windows VM from the host OS? From itself? (What I'm asking is, does it respond to ICMP packets correctly in the first place?)

Answer (score 0):

Any antivirus on the Windows box that may have shipped with it's own firewall as well? How about iptables on the centos box? Have you disabled that too? Have you run a traceroute to see if it's trying to take the path you think it is?

Comment: The Windows VM responds to pings from itself. No antivirus on the Windows VM, fresh install from ISO just a couple of days ago. I stopped the iptables service (/etc/init.d/iptables stop) and still no joy. Route table shows that it is using the proper device for the subnet. Tracert complains that it can't find the host, so it never even leaves the device. I am just baffled by this one...

Comment: @El Hombre Can you post your network settings from both systems?